# Divide screen with vertical and horizontal lines/Views

Tags: java, android, view, nullpointerexception

Below is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

The green line is a vertical line that will be a simple View.  The red line will be a horizontal line that will also be a simple view.  I want the red line X amount of dps/pixels from the top of the RelativeLayout.  Then I want the green line centered horizontally and then stretching from the top of the RelativeLayout to "above the red line".

Below is my code that compiles but produces a run-time error.

```
public class Puzzle extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout relativelayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

        dividers();

        setContentView(relativelayout);
    }

    public void dividers() {

        // horizontal line
        View view0 = new View(this);
        view0.setBackgroundColor(0xFFC2BEBF);
        relativelayout.addView(view0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
        view0.setId(0);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = null;
        params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);    // line 39
        view0.setLayoutParams(params0);

        // vertical line
        View view1 = new View(this);
        view1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFC2BEBF);
        relativelayout.addView(view1, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = null;
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, view0.getId());
        view1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    }
}
```

Below is the LogCat output.

```
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140): Process: matt.lyons.tileslider, PID: 4140
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{matt.lyons.tileslider/matt.lyons.tileslider.Puzzle}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at matt.lyons.tileslider.Puzzle.dividers(Puzzle.java:39)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at matt.lyons.tileslider.Puzzle.onCreate(Puzzle.java:24)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-22 00:25:02.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4140):     ... 11 more
```

I have commented into my code where line 39 is.  I am new to doing an entire layout in Java with no XML so I am a little confused on how to do this so any help is appreciated.  Why am I getting this NPE?

Comment: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = null;` and you are surprised to have a NPE at the next line?

Comment: Well I didn't want to input 2 numbers there for the height and width since I declared the size of the View a few lines above it like this:  `relativelayout.addView(view0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));`.  I guess I just don't know what to set `params0` equal to.

Comment: haw about new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2)` since you already use pretty much this 2 lines before?

Comment: @njzk2 that is the answer!  Feel free to write it as an Answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Initialize` `params0`  Like Below then You can use `addRule`

```
params0 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
```

Comment: This resulted in no run-time error but the View takes up the entire screen.  I need thin divider lines like the picture in the opening post.

Answer (score 1):

try this one you can change the width,height and color according to you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<View
    android:layout_width="0.5dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#DF5555" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#E66666" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My goal is to do this purely in Java; no XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = **null**;
   // param0 variable is not initialise 
    params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);    // line 39
    view0.setLayoutParams(params0);
```

also this part

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = **null**;
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

initialise the part

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);;
```